# searching on sql the item that not exist on other table

Tags: sql-server, join

i have the script like this:

```
SELECT   NO_ORDRE
      ,[CODE_CLIENT]
      ,[DATE_CLOTUR_REEL]
        FROM [ORDRE]
    where CODE_CLIENT = '50929'
      AND DATEPART(YEAR,DATE_CLOTUR)=2015 AND DATEPART(MONTH,DATE_CLOTUR)=11
     -- order by NO_ORDRE,CODE_CLIENT

      EXCEPT

      SELECT [NO_ORDRE]    
      ,[CODE_CLIENT]
      ,DATE_CLOTUR_REEL
      FROM [LETTRE_VOIT]
       where CODE_CLIENT = '50929'
      AND DATEPART(YEAR,DATE_CLOTURE)=2015 AND DATEPART(MONTH,DATE_CLOTURE)=11
```

that work well, but when i change `CODE_CLIENT = '50929'` into `CODE_CLIENT like '50%'`

it not work what i expected...it selected all item

any idea ?

Comment: Doesn't work? How did you guess that it didn;t work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT O.NO_ORDRE, O.[CODE_CLIENT], O.[DATE_CLOTUR_REEL]
FROM [ORDRE] O
LEFT JOIN [LETTRE_VOIT] L
    ON O.CODE_CLIENT = L.CODE_CLIENT
        AND DATEPART(YEAR,O.DATE_CLOTUR) = DATEPART(YEAR,L.DATE_CLOTUR)
        AND DATEPART(MONTH,O.DATE_CLOTUR) = DATEPART(MONTH,L.DATE_CLOTUR)
WHERE O.CODE_CLIENT = '50929'
    AND DATEPART(YEAR,O.DATE_CLOTUR)=2015 AND DATEPART(MONTH,O.DATE_CLOTUR)=11
    AND L.CODE_CLIENT IS NULL
```